# links__system_main_menu in drupal

Tags: php, drupal-7

what is the use of `links__system_main_menu` in drupal?

```
 <?php if ($main_menu): ?>
      <div id="main-menu" class="navigation">
        <?php print theme('links__system_main_menu', array(
          'links' => $main_menu,
          'attributes' => array(
            'id' => 'main-menu-links',
            'class' => array('links', 'clearfix'),
          ),
          'heading' => array(
            'text' => t('Main menu'),
            'level' => 'h2',
            'class' => array('element-invisible'),
          ),
        )); ?>
      </div> <!-- /#main-menu -->
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a pattern for theme hook, in the form [base hook]__[context]. When links theme with `theme('links__system_main_menu', $variables)`, `theme()` function search for *theme_links__system_main_menu()* and use it. Otherwise, if it doesn't find, it will use *theme_links()*. For more information check the [theme Doc](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!theme.inc/function/theme/7)